# How can I sort my file by date if there are different number of spaces between the name and date?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

How can I sort my file by date if there are different number of spaces between the name and date?
My example file:

```
Ivanov      03/01/1980
Petrov      10/05/1992
Sidorov     21/07/1985
Kovtun      15/09/1976
Volnii      06/11/2000
Anisin      20/04/1998
Kovalenko   25/08/1982
Antonov     18/12/1990
Vlasenko    09/02/1987
Artiukh     30/10/1995
Shevchenko  26/05/2004
```

I tried something like that but it doesn't work

```
sort -k2,2 name_and_birthday.txt > sorted_by_birth.txt
```

This works, but it removes extra spaces, but at the expense of using awk and removing extra spaces this option does not work for me.

```
sort -k 2.7,2.10 -k 2.4,2.5 -k 2.1,2.2 -t ' ' -u <(awk '{$1=$1}1' name_and_birthday) > sorted_by_birth.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
sort -b -k2.7,2.10 -k2.4,2.5 -k2.1,2.2 name_and_birthday.txt > sorted_by_birth.txt
```

- `-b`: This option tells sort to ignore leading blanks in each line.
- `-k`: This option specifies the key used for sorting. In your case, you have specified three keys separated by commas:
- `2.7,2.10`: This sorts based on characters 7 through 10 of the second field (column) of each line. This is likely the year part of the birthdate.
- `2.4,2.5`: This sorts based on characters 4 through 5 of the second field
- `2.1,2.2`: This sorts based on characters 1 through 2 of the second field

Finally, `name_and_birthday.txt` is the input file, and the sorted output is redirected to a file named `sorted_by_birth.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, I learnt something here. I always took `-b` to ignore spaces at the beginning of line only, I didn't realise it "compacts" consecutive spaces down ...

Answer (score 0):

For shits and giggles a `gawk` only implementation (very convoluted):

```
$ cat a
{
  split($2,d,"/")
  a[d[3]d[2]d[1]]=$0
}
END{
  n=asorti(a,b)
  for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
    print a[b[i]]
  }
}
```

And run like so:

```
$ awk -f a example 
Kovtun      15/09/1976
Ivanov      03/01/1980
Kovalenko   25/08/1982
Sidorov     21/07/1985
Vlasenko    09/02/1987
Antonov     18/12/1990
Petrov      10/05/1992
Artiukh     30/10/1995
Anisin      20/04/1998
Volnii      06/11/2000
Shevchenko  26/05/2004
```

Having to use the `split` to get there makes a strong case for using **ISO 8601** date formats. ;) They would sort correctly naturally.

Comment: +1 vote for ISO8601 dates; without it you get ambiguous dates (which order does the fields have?), that are hard to handle (as shown above).